# How can I sort PDF by date in Adobe Acrobat on iOS?

Tags: ios, pdf

How can I sort PDF by date in Adobe Acrobat on iOS? By default the order is lexicographical:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking on "recent" sort the documents by descending date of last opening:

[image]